# How do I convert Marklogic REST query (qbe) to an executable query on Marlogic console?

Tags: marklogic

Here is a REST query (using python) that I would like to convert as a Marklogic console query in order for me to check details.

```js
url = self.url + "qbe?collection=" + colName+ "&pageLength=50"

query = { "$query": { "$and" : [
                    {"id" : 1 },
                    {"name" : "Elizabeth" },
                    ]}
                }

response = requests.post(url=url, data=json.dumps(query), headers=headers, auth=self.auth)
```

and what should I put in "query type". Sorry for this newbie question. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat convoluted but I'm not aware of an alternative. I'll probably remove this answer if a simpler alternative is shared.

First, you'll want to add `&view=structured&format=xml` to your URL.

The response you get back will look something like this:

```
<search:search xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">

<search:query>
<search:value-query>
<search:element ns="" name="author"/>
<search:text>Mark Twain</search:text>
<search:term-option>exact</search:term-option>
</search:value-query>
<search:value-query>
<search:element ns="" name="edition"/>
<search:attribute ns="" name="format"/>
<search:text>paperback</search:text>
<search:term-option>exact</search:term-option>
</search:value-query>
</search:query>

<search:options>
<search:search-option>unfiltered</search:search-option>
<search:search-option>format-xml</search:search-option>
<search:quality-weight>0</search:quality-weight>
<search:return-facets>true</search:return-facets>
<search:return-results>true</search:return-results>
</search:options>

</search:search>
```

Using this response you can run `search:resolve` via XQuery in QConsole like so:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
     at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

search:resolve(
<search:query xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
<search:value-query>
<search:element ns="" name="author"/>
<search:text>Mark Twain</search:text>
<search:term-option>exact</search:term-option>
</search:value-query>
<search:value-query>
<search:element ns="" name="edition"/>
<search:attribute ns="" name="format"/>
<search:text>paperback</search:text>
<search:term-option>exact</search:term-option>
</search:value-query>
</search:query>,

<search:options xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
<search:search-option>unfiltered</search:search-option>
<search:quality-weight>0</search:quality-weight>
<search:return-facets>true</search:return-facets>
<search:return-results>true</search:return-results>
<search:debug>true</search:debug>
</search:options>
)
```

Note that I added `<search:debug>true</search:debug>` to the second XML parameter. **This is important.**

In your result from this function you will see an element called `search:report` which will contain the cts:query that the QBE is actually running.

```
<search:report id="SEARCH-FLWOR">(cts:search(fn:collection(), cts:and-query((cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("","author"), "Mark Twain", ("case-sensitive","diacritic-sensitive","punctuation-sensitive","whitespace-sensitive","unstemmed","unwildcarded","lang=en"), 1), cts:element-attribute-value-query(fn:QName("","edition"), fn:QName("","format"), "paperback", ("case-sensitive","diacritic-sensitive","punctuation-sensitive","whitespace-sensitive","unstemmed","unwildcarded","lang=en"), 1)), ()), ("unfiltered",cts:score-order("descending")), 0))[1 to 10]</search:report>
```

You can copy the contents of this element and run it as an XQuery in QConsole on its own.

Comment: The final step of converting the structured query to a cts query might not be necessary depending on what you're investigating in Query Console. Also, note that the latest version of the /v1/qbe endpoint can take a view=ctsquery value to get back a cts query.

Comment: @ehennum Good to know. Not on the latest so it doesnt seem supported for me. Also, that option doesn't appear to be documented: https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/qbe .